# Viewport in conjugation with html body styling

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

I'm at a loss. I don't understand how to use style html and body in conjugation with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,"/>
```

to make my website([huskybiz.com](https://huskybiz.com)) not be zoomed in on load on mobile and to have a min-width of 800 and max-width of 2000. I've been trying for days. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

set user-scalable attribute to no (user-scalable=no)

if you assign it to user-scalable=no, it means the website is not allowing the user to zoom in or zoom out.

you can also use  `maximum-scale=1` it also won’t allow the user to zoom.

Reference:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#Attributes